# How to connect virtual server with physical laptop

Tags: connection

I need some help
 I have a laptop on which two virtual machine Window Xp and server 2008 are installed and they are connected with "internal Network" to each other. Now i want to connect this virtual network with my laptop,if it is not possible then only the server with laptop but I have no idea.
 Please help me if any one can do

Comment: Firewall issue perhaps?

Comment: What virtualization platform are you using? What is the exact network type you're using for connecting the hosts?

Comment: Are all three systems (laptop, XP VM, W2k8 VM) on the internet? What are their IP addresses?

Comment: Don't give the IP addresses. Just make up some.

Comment: XP and W2k8 are virtual machine without internet and have ip's 10.0.10.1 of W2k8 and 10.0.10.5 of Xp and laptop have internet of ip 192.168.3.102 means different range

Comment: Change the adapter to bridged mode.

Comment: Ansgar (above) is asking for "virtualization platform" info. Are you using: Virtualbox, vmware, or some other software?